# Spring Security Logout From Stateless server

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a stateless REST API with spring boot.
Therefore I am using a token based authentication.

Currently the logout functionality is only implemented on the client side.
I just clear all cookies.

Problem is that the user object seems to survive the request so it still exists in the next requests.
My service to get the current user is simply:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
  private User user;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository;

  public User get() {
    if (user != null) {
      return user;
    }
    Integer id = (Integer) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    user = userRepository.findById(id);
    return user;
  }
}
```

I would expect that the user variable is null on every request? The funny thing is that the correct user id is set in the security context. But the service returns the user object because it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use user as a class attribute.

UserService is a singleton, what happens when you have concurrent requests coming from different users?
Move this variable inside the get method.

Moreover, if you are using JWT as the token based authentication take a look at this [project](https://github.com/brahalla/Cerberus).

With JWT you can retrieve the user required informations directly from the token without performing any queries.

Comment: But even if the service is a singleton, I would expect that the singleton lifetime is only request-bound. It seems like spring is caching the singleton services? Otherwise I cannot imagine how the user attribute can exist in the next requests.

Comment: By default if you specify only the annotation **Service** there can only  be one UserService class per time (only one instance of this class). You can specify the scope of a bean trough the annotation **Scope** but I don't recommend this solution.

Comment: but is this one instance shared through multiple requests?

Comment: Yea it is the same istance, with the user property shared by every caller.
Btw make sure that spring initialise this Service through component scanning and don't initialise it with `new UserService();`.

Comment: OK thanks. I didnt know that a singleton can "survive" a request. :-) Simply removing the class attribute solved my problem. (I hope it wont be a performance issue later because now hibernate will fetch every time I call get() the user from the database)

Comment: Take a look at [JWT](https://jwt.io/) if you want to avoid performing auth queries. Also look at the project linked in my answer, hope it'll be useful.